# Cannot read file with same URL and same file structure on different computer

Tags: java, url, filepath, ioexception

So I wrote a small application that uses a string that represents a filepath so I can create a file and then a buffered Image. I have omitted irrelevant code for this example:

```
public class MorphImage {
private final String URL0 = "pic1.jpg";

//....

URL url = getClass().getResource(URL0);
File file = new File(url.getPath());
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
```

My file structure is as follows:

```
 projectName
            src
               package1
                       MorphImage.java
                       pic1.jpg
```

On my laptop running Windows 10, this works just fine, but using the exact same project on my Windows 8 pc, I get an `IIOException: Can't read file!` on the last row. Both computers use the same Eclipse version and same JDK version. I'm not sure what to do here. I have tried many different filepaths on my Windows 8 machine but that only throws NP instead, so the path is correct.

EDIT: Solution below:

```
    URL defaultImage = MorphImage.class.getResource(URL0);
    File file = new File(defaultImage.toURI());
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get as resource stream ,with the file path as below

getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("package1/pic1.jpg");

Comment: This actually worked, thanks, will edit the solution to my post.